# HttpURLConnection unexpected status line

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am receiving an extra byte in some of the responses from the server
when using HttpURLConnection, the resonse should be HTTP/1.1 200 OK,
but I have been reciving a Zero in front of the response and that is causing an exception and I do not know why, probably I am sending request very fast,
the problem is that it happens randomly. For what I have research, persisten connections some times send and extra byte between chunks of data, the problem is why the HttpURLConnection doesn't know how to handle this?? this is the error, the strange character at the beggining is a Zero byte:

java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: ��HTTP/1.1 200 OK
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.setStatusLine(RawHeaders.java:108)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:308)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:135)

Does anyone know how to fix this? The exception is thrown when trying to get the input stream, and that

here is the code I am using:

```
            String postURL = this._http_connection;
            con = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(postURL)).openConnection();             
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);              
            con.setConnectTimeout(_timeout);
            con.setReadTimeout(_timeout);
            con.setUseCaches(false);                
            con.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
            HttpResponseCache.setDefault(null);

            Log.v("doInBackground", "HttDataTask: 1");              

            if(this._httpParams != null && this._httpParams.size() > 0)
            {
                byte [] buffer = ("=" + _httpParams.get(0).toString()).getBytes();
                con.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                con.getOutputStream().close();
            }
            Log.v("doInBackground", "HttDataTask: 2");

            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            stream = con.getInputStream();
            byte buffer [] = new byte[10240];
            int len = 0;
```

Here is an article that talks about that, but I do not know how to fix the problem, how can I tell HttpURLConnection to ignore this byte or to handle it?

https://www.subbu.org/blog/2004/11/persistent-connections-pipelining-and-chunking

The server runs in Internet Information Server with REST apis. Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: You're not writing  the `httpParams` correctly. The body of a POST request consists of name=value pairs separated by `&`.

Comment: You are correct, except that I am not downloding webpages, I am using custom REST API data, everything works ok using the same pattern, but sometimes the response adds an extra Zero to the chunk and that creates an exception so I have to make a retry to get the response without the zero.